# Creating a sequence scheme in MYSQL without AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sequence

I want to run a sequence, scoped to each client so they each have a series of ID's starting from 1:

```
Clients:
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Dave  |
|  2 | Sarah |
+----+-------+

Tickets:
+----+-----------+----------+----------------------------+
| id | clientID  | sequence |  title                     |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------------------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 | Title 1                    |
|  2 |         1 |        2 | Another title for Client 1 |
|  3 |         2 |        1 | Different Title            |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Whats the best way to do this (in terms of speed and data integrity)? I have something like this upon inserting:

Add new ticket for Dave

```
SELECT COALESCE( (MAX(sequence) + 1), 1) as nextSeq WHERE id = 1 FROM tickets
```

then

```
INSERT INTO tickets (... sequence) VALUES (... nextSeq)
```

**What's the COALESCE for?**

When ever the record is first in it's series, the MAX() will return empty, so default empty to 1.

**Why I want a user-scoped sequence number?**

It's a document capture system, displaying lots of tabular data, I have multiple entities; System, Risk, Ticket, Process and I'm using numbers with titles to help users keep track of their records. Whilst in tables, the initial result will be ordered by this ID, hence I don't want a global ID numbering. I leave the auto_incremented column for other backend operations, joins, private referencing etc.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Can you access Window/Analytic functions ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya 5.7 so I don't think so

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as one statement

```
   INSERT 
     INTO ticket (clientID, sequence, title)
   SELECT clientID,
          MAX(sequence) + 1,
          "Dave's New Ticket"
     FROM ticket
    WHERE clientID = 1 /** Dave */
 GROUP BY clientID
```

.. but I'm not totally sure about the performance compared to two separate statements. Note, the GROUP BY is actually optional in MySQL

It is also worth questioning whether a sequence number is in itself absolutely necessary, and what you are trying to accomplish with it